# Mystery of the invisible text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a site with a simple navigation bar. I've written some CSS to show a hover-effect for the buttons. Everything works fine in IE and FF but for some reason in Chrome the menu button text labels are invisible rendering the menu utterly useless. I spent over an hour researching a solution but can't find anything.  I installed firebug lite in Chrome and spent a while trying to get the labels to display by adding z-index rules, changing the label color and removing backgrounds etc etc but nothing will make them appear.

If anyone wants to see this in action try looking at http://naamjoga.cz first in FF and then in Chrome. Any help gratefully appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating your links to the left and instead you want to float your list items to the left. Just tested this and the following changes fixes your problem. It doesn't really make sense to be floating your links left anyways.

`#nav ul li { float: left; }` instead of `#nav li a { float: left; }`

Comment: Thanks for the points. I can finally comment! There are so many smart people on SO that formulating a correct and concise answer super fast is really hard to do.

Comment: Congratulations! Don't geek out too much though :) I reckon some of these 'smart people' must spend far too much time on here to accumulate so many points.

Answer (score 0):

In my dev version of Chrome, it works as you want if you add `display: inline;` to your `#nav ul li` styles. Once you've made that change, check it still works in FF and IE.

Comment: Hi - and thanks for your answer. Actually I saw that you've already got 13.4K points so I figured I'd try mrtsherman's answer first - he's only got 26! ;) His answer worked. I hope that's OK - this is my first post on stackoverflow so I'm not 100% about the etiquette in this situation where there are two answers to check.

Comment: @Xoundboy: The usual approach is to upvote each answer you think is useful (by clicking the up arrow to the left of each answer), and accept the answer you find the best (as you have already done).

Comment: Right, that makes sense. It looks like I need 15 points before I can upvote. That might take a while. Thanks for the advice.